# Updating without copying

Tags: rsync, file-copy

Given a source and destination directory, how can I update files that
have newer versions in the source, but *not* copy any files that do not
already exist in the destination (in *any* version)?

That is, if the source has a 1000 files, and the destination has only 2,
1 file
that is newer than the corresponding in the source and 1 that is older,
I want the older one replaced, and I do not want the remaining 999 copied.

Answer (score 2):

From the `rsync` manual:

```
--existing  skip creating new files on receiver
```

Ref: https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync